# Why is the filter in this calculate measure not working?

Tags: sql, powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I'm creating the following measure to count the number of dimension table rows within a category in PowerBI:

`TotalNonSev = Calculate(COUNT(DimCrime[CrimeNumber]), FILTER(DimCrime, DimCrime[CrimeGroup] = "least severe"))`

Without the filter, the total number of columns is displayed as expected, but after the filter is added the result is [blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c6mUw.png).

[Here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qzfmw.png) is the actual table with the category being filtered upon - I've ensured that there are actually rows that fit the condition and that the lowercase values of CrimeGroup are the same as in the filter.

Does anyone have an idea as to why this is occurring? The solution may be very basic as I am quite new to PowerBI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Keep search string in double quotes "" "".

```
TotalNonSev = Calculate(COUNT(DimCrime[CrimeNumber]), FILTER(DimCrime, DimCrime[CrimeGroup] = """least severe"""))
```

Comment: Thank you! as an aside, where I am doing analysis based on dimension tables like this, is it generally better to try and count the number of rows for a condition as I have done, or to use SUM and create a dummy variable full of '1' counts?

Comment: Do as above, its fine

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this?

TotalNonSev = CALCULATE( COUNTROWS(FILTER('DimCrime', DimCrime[CrimeGroup] = "least severe")))